# Remove padding between two filledcurves in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot two filledcurves side by side. But they are not touching each other, instead there is a white gap in between. How to remove it?

I tried to decrease the start and increase the end x value of the midde filledcurve but still there is a gap between them. It's like some default behavious of filledcurves.

Here's the gnuplot script

```
set title "Quantile"
set yrange[0:1.1]
set xlabel("x")

N(x) = 1/(sqrt(2*pi))*(exp(-x**2/2))
N1(x) = (x<=-1.96 || x>=1.96)? 1/(sqrt(2*pi))*(exp(-(x)**2/2)): 1/0
N2(x) = (x>=-1.96 && x<=1.96)? 1/(sqrt(2*pi))*(exp(-x**2/2)):1/0
set output "Quantile.png"
plot N1(x)  with filledcurves y1=0 lc "cyan", N2(x) with filledcurves y1=0, N(x) with lines title "Normal Distribution" lw 2.5,
pause -1
```

The output, I am getting

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When plotting functions, gnuplot uses a certain number of samples, default is 100 (check `help samples`). So, increase this number until the gap is sufficiently small.

So, add a line, for example:

```
set samples 1000
```

**Addition:**

Here is an alternative approach using plotting style `with boxes` and variable color and of course `set samples 1000`. Check `help boxes` and `help variable`. Instead of `plot f(x)` you could also write `plot '+' u 1:(f($1))`, check `help special-filenames`.

I'm not sure if there is a way using `with filledcurves` **and** variable color.

**Script:**

```
### fill area under curve with variable color
reset session

set xlabel "x"
set xrange[-5:5]
set yrange[0:0.42]
set key noautotitle
set style fill solid 1.0 noborder
set samples 1000

N(x)       = 1/(sqrt(2*pi))*(exp(-x**2/2))
myColor(x) = abs(x)<=1.96 ? 0xff0000 : 0x0000ff

plot '+' u 1:(N($1)):(myColor($1)) w boxes lc rgb var, \
     N(x) w lines title "Normal Distribution" lw 2.5 lc "black"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Yup, that worked. What are samples here? What do they signify in the graph?

Comment: @SumitGupta the samples are the number of points on the x-axis which are used to plot the function, check `help samples`. For example, if you have a 1000 pixel wide graph and samples is 100, there will be a point every 10 pixels. For further reading: `plot f(x)` is basically the same as `plot '+' u 1:(f($1))`. Check `help special-filenames`.